# JqueryGrid plugin getting selected row id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using the [jqueryGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) plugin. I want to implement the easy edit function. The user will click a jquery grid column with an edit button. Then they will redirect to the edit view. I want to do that. But i must get selected column's id value. So my code is shown below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#list').width(200);
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Credential/JqueryGridData/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Sıra', 'Resim', 'İsim', 'Başlık', 'Açıklama', 'Boyut',  'Oluşturulma Tarihi', 'Güncellenme Tarihi'],
            colModel: [
                 { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 10, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Order', index: 'Order', width: 10, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'Image', index: 'Image', width: 50, height: 25, align: 'center'  },
              { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 40, align: 'left', search: true,  stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
              { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 40, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 100, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'Size', index: 'Size', width: 20, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'CreatedDate', index: 'CreatedDate', width: 20, align: 'center'  },
              { name: 'UpdatedDate', index: 'UpdatedDate', width: 20, align: 'center'  }],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            editurl: '/Credential/JqueryGridData/?id=44',
            loadtext: 'Yükleniyor lütfen bekleyiniz',
            rowNum: 17,
            rowList: [17, 34, 53, 70],
            sortname: 'Id',
            width: 1100,
            height: 400,
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
            caption: 'Referans Listesi'
        });
        $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
 { /* parameters */
     edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: 'Ara', refreshtext: 'Yenile'
 },
 { /* edit options */ },
 { /* add options */ },
 { /* delete options */ },
 { /* search options */
     multipleSearch: false,
     multipleGroup: false,
     showQuery: false,
     top: 190,
     left: 200,
     caption: "Ara",
     closeAfterSearch: true,
     sopt: ['cn'],
 },
  { /* view options */ }
);
        $('#pager_left').append('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  class="ui-pg-table navtable" style="float:left;table-layout:auto;"><tbody><tr><td  class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Yeni" id="search_list2"><div class="ui-pg-div"><a  href="/Management/Credential/Create/"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a></div> </td></tr></tbody></table>');
        $('#pager_left').append('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  class="ui-pg-table navtable" style="float:left;table-layout:auto;"><tbody><tr><td  class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Düzenle" id="search_list2"><div class="ui-pg- div"><a href="/Management/Credential/Edit/5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>   </a></div></td></tr></tbody></table>');
    });
</script>
```

I added edit button with this line :

```
  $('#pager_left').append('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ui-  pg-table navtable" style="float:left;table-layout:auto;"><tbody><tr><td class="ui-pg-button   ui-corner-all" title="Düzenle" id="search_list2"><div class="ui-pg-div"><a   href="/Management/Credential/Edit/5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></a></div>  </td></tr></tbody></table>');
```

In this line "/Management/Credential/Edit/5" i must send to selected row id to the controller. What am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set "editable:true" to the column where u want to edit.

then add the following code:

```
onSelectRow: function(id,e){
 jQuery('#list').editRow(id)
}
```

and you can't send the parameters in editurl. you have a call back "extraparam" for inline editing to send the parameters.
refer [this] http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

Answer (score 0):

With you current approach, you will have to select a row first and then on click for edit, then the selection. This is more involved.

Another approach is to add edit on each line using a formatter.

Add below to list of columns
    { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', width: 20, align: 'center', formatter:editFormatter }

Add to javascript
    function editFormatter(cellvalue, options, row) {
            var id = row["Id"];
            return '';
        }